# How to animate TextSpan or part of a text in Flutter like in this game screenshot?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

Do you have any pointers on how to animate TextSpan or part of a text in Flutter to achieve the same effect than in this game screenshot?

[image: screenshot]

I know how to animate a whole text with typewriter effect but not how to animate only part of the text.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

There are packages that can do that, for example https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/animated-text-in-flutter/ using the `animated_text_kit`

```
AnimatedTextKit(
                 animatedTexts: [
                   TyperAnimatedText('This is Animated text,',
                       textStyle: const TextStyle(
                           color: Colors.white,
                           fontSize: 30,
                           backgroundColor: Colors.purple)),
                   TyperAnimatedText('You are viewing it here.',
                       textStyle: const TextStyle(
                           fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                 ],
                 onTap: () {
                   print("I am executing");
                 },
               ),
```

Comment: Thanks Anton! I checked out this package already. The issue is that they are standalone widgets, it does not integrate into a sentence like in the screenshot. There should be a way to have a RichText widget and animate some of its TextSpan to get the same feeling than the screenshot.

Comment: I believe the solution is using the RichText widget key and modifying its state like this: https://bigzhu.net/tips/add-animation-to-flutter-textspan/ but haven't tested and try to tweak it yet :)